# How can I assign a scoring with the same scale?

Tags: excel, statistics

[image: Here i have the same scale for 5 options and for 3 options but how do i do it if for example i have 7 options?]

Thank you for helping me to understand how do i assign scoring with comparable scales

Comment: To me it is not clear what you are asking for. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. At least you should show us your expected result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Will you have a table for some contributor with number of tools, and no of company incentives, and you want to compile the scores based on that scoring schema you listed?

One way you could do it is to create a table with your data (Applicant, No tools, Tools Score, No incentives, Incentives Score)

[image: Example Table:]

The two score columns I have created using nested IF Formulas.

```
'for Tools score:

=IF(B2=1,1,IF(B2=2,2,(IF(B2=3,6,IF(B2=4,8,IF(B2=5,10,0))))))
```

For the case where it is none of the options you list for number of tools, I have set it to give a score of 0.  Probably harsh for those over achievers! :P

That is the third argument in this section zero here: `IF(B2=5,10,0)`

```
'for Incentives Score

=IF(E2=1, 1, IF(AND(E2>=2,E2<=6),6,IF(E2>=7,10,0)))
```